ngx-codemirror html formatting
I would like to display a complex html "string" in codemirror with line breaks at the respective tags. However, the formatting of the code does not work when it is initially created (HTML is displayed as a long string without line breaks). The text is an BehaviorSubject
codemirrorOptions are following:
codemirrorOptions = {
  theme: 'material-darker',
  lineNumbers: true,
  lineWrapping: 'true',
  fullScreen: true,
  mode: 'htmlmixed',
  autoCloseBrackets: true,
  matchBrackets: true,
  gutters: ['CodeMirror-linenumbers',
    'CodeMirror-foldgutter'
  ],
  foldGutter: true,
};

Text is implemented like:
@Input() text: BehaviorSubject<string>;

Codemirror in html:
<ngx-codemirror (ngModelChange)="text.next($event)" [ngModel]="(text | async)" [options]="codemirrorOptions"></ngx-codemirror>

Text example:
<h3><strong>Vorteile/Nutzen</strong></h3>
<ul>
    <li>4-fach Spreizung garantiert höchste Haltewerte.</li>
</ul>

